# Auto Scheduled VB Script

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I need help in creating a VB Script which needs to open at a specific day and time. I need to avoid using Task Scheduler because, I will be sharing this VBS file to other users and the task has to be scheduled the first time the user runs this script.

Comment: Please show us your code so far. If you are yet to write anything, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601(v=vs.85).aspx may be a good starting point.

Comment: `ans = MsgBox("Do you want to check NIFTY 100?", vbYesNo, "NIFTY 100!!")

Select Case ans
Case vbYes

    xlpath = "E:\Swami\Investment\NIFTY_100.xlsm"
    Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    With xlapp
        .Visible = True
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        Set wbk = .Workbooks.Open(xlpath)
    End With
    
End Select`

Comment: Above is the code i have so far....to allow user to choose Yes or No, which then opens an xlsm file. I wish to schedule an automated task so that this prompt appears every weekday at a specific time.

Comment: Based on [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394601(v=vs.85).aspx] I have come up with below code....i want it to schedule a task at 10:00 AM (GMT + 5:30) Indian Standard Time on all weekdays. Please advise!!!

Comment: `strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 
JobID = "SchTest"
Set objNewJob = objWMIService.Get("Win32_ScheduledJob")
errJobCreate = objNewJob.Create _
    ("C:\Users\adimessi\Desktop\VB Scheduler.vbs", "********100000.000000-330", True , 1 OR 2 OR 4 OR 8 OR 16, ,True, JobId)`

Comment: `If errJobCreate = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Job created successfully: " & VBNewLine _
        & "VB Scheduler.vbs scheduled to run repeately at 10.00 (10:00 A.M.) IST" & VBNewLine _
        & "on all Weekdays."
Else
    WScript.Echo "Job not created. Error code = " & errJobCreate
End If`

Comment: Any help guys??

Comment: Is there a problem with the new script you have written? If so, what's the error message?

Comment: I have finally come up with below code which waits until the time is 11:30 AM and then repeats every hour......please share your thoughts on this...

Comment: `Do While(FormatDateTime(Now, vbShortTime) <> "11:30")
   WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

while true

'My code to call the macro file........

wscript.sleep(60*60*1000)

wend`

Comment: I plan to place this vbs file in the startup folder so that it starts everytime the user logins for the day.....will this work??